# JAXB, Hibernate, Lazy loading

Tags: hibernate, jaxb, resteasy

I have a simple Hibernate POJO pasted below (constructors and setters removed for brevity).  My problem arises with the "User" relations.  Hibernate lazy-loads the relation just fine, however when my CRUD webservice call (also below) marshalls an instance of this object, it calls the relation's "get" method thus throwing a "No transaction" exception in Hibernate because JAXB isn't accessing the relation inside of either a session or transaction.

POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ldapservers", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "hostname"))
@XmlRootElement(name = "ldap-server")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class LdapServer implements Serializable
{
    private int ldapServerId;
    private String hostname;
    private int port;
    private Date createDate;
    private String createUser;
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(0);
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ldapServerID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    public int getLdapServerId()
    {
        return this.ldapServerId;
    }
    @Column(name = "hostname", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @XmlElement
    public String getHostname()
    {
        return this.hostname;
    }
    @Column(name = "port", nullable = false)
    @XmlElement
    public int getPort()
    {
        return this.port;
    }
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = false, length = 19)
    @XmlAttribute(name="create-date")
    public Date getCreateDate()
    {
        return this.createDate;
    }
    @Column(name = "createUser", nullable = false)
    @XmlAttribute(name="create-user")
    public String getCreateUser()
    {
        return this.createUser;
    }
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ldapServer")
    public Set<User> getUsers()
    {
        return this.users;
    }
}
```

WebService Call:

```
    @GET
@Path("/fetch/{id}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public LdapServer getLdapServer(@PathParam("id") int ldapServerID)
{
    logger.debug("Fetching LdapServer ID "+ldapServerID);
    LdapServer ls = this.home.findById(ldapServerID);

    if (ls!=null)
    {
        logger.debug("Found LdapServer ID "+ldapServerID);
    }
    else
    {
        logger.debug("LdapServer ID "+ldapServerID+" not found.");
    }

    return ls;
}
```

I have not included the DAO/EJB code because the error occurs within Resteasy and outside of this call, indicating that the problem occurs during marshalling.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem too a while back. I'm assuming that you have a hibernate session and transaction open at the start of the resteasy method and you are closing it at the end of the method. The problem is that lazy loading will return a proxy object to Users. You can step debug it and run ls.getUsers(). The type is a proxy. It will only fetch the actual object once you access something in that proxy. In your case this happens during marshalling, but by that point, your session/transaction have been closed so your error comes up. If you were to access something like ls.getUsers.size() within the resteasy method, the the proxy will now be the actual object you are expecting and the marshalling will work, but it seems messy to have to do this. Back when I had the problem, I simply decided to do eager and avoid this mess. Now, however, there is a fix that you can see here https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7457